# Flutter's Hero Transition above the other

Tags: flutter, dart

I have two screens with 2 heroes between them:

- One is the AppBar
- The second is a CircularAvatar

Both are inside a stack, and obviously the CircularAvatar is above the Appbar.

This gif shows the problem: realize how the CircularAvatar comes from behind the AppBar and then POPS above it when the transition is done.

[image]

This is my first screen (containg the cards with people photos):
[image]

This is my second screen:
[image]

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.2.1, on Microsoft Windows [versÃ£o 10.0.17763.379], locale pt-BR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.3)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2018.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.30.1)
[√] Connected device (1 available)

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score -2):

First at all i think that the hero in the AppBar its not need it, please try to remove that hero and just have your gridview hero jump to the next place located in the second screen Appbar.

Comment: It is needed because I want to cause an AppBar cool size transition.